# Clustering GPS points with a custom distance function in scipy

Tags: python, gps, scipy, cluster-analysis

I'm curious if it is possible to specify your own distance function between two points for scipy clustering. I have datapoints with 3 values: GPS-lat, GPS-lon, and posix-time. I want to cluster these points using some algorithm: either agglomerative clustering, meanshift, or something else.

The problem is distance between GPS points needs to be calculated with the Haversine formula. And then that distance needs to be weighted appropriately so it is comparable with a distance in seconds for clustering purposes.

Looking at the documentation for scipy I don't see anything that jumps out as a way to specify a custom distance between two points.

Is there another way I should be going about this? I'm curious what the Pythonic thing to do is.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for sklearn, but I don't have a good answer for you there. Basically, you could build a distance matrix the way you like, and many algorithms will process the distance matrix. The problem is that this needs O(n^2) memory.

For my attempts at clustering geodata, I have instead used [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) (which is Java, not Python). First of all, it includes geodetic distance functions; but it also includes index acceleration for many algorithms *and* for this distance function.

I have not used an additional attribute such as time. As you already noticed you need to weight them appropriately, as 1 meter does not equal not 1 second. Weights will be very much use case dependant, and heuristic.

Why I'm suggesting ELKI is because they have a nice [Tutorial on implementing custom distance functions](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/DistanceFunctions) that then can be used in most algorithms. They can't be used in every algorithm - some don't use distance at all, or are constrained to e.g. Minkowski metrics only. But a lot of algorithms can use arbitrary (even non-metric) distance functions.

There also is a follow-up tutorial on [index accelerated distance functions](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/SpatialDistanceFunctions). For my geodata, indexes were tremendously useful, speeding up by a factor of over 100x, and thus enabling be to process 10 times more data.